# convert CST time string to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

How can I covert a time string which contains CST to datetime object?

```
ts = "Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need ***[`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)*** function to achieve your requirement. Something like:

```py
# Create a dictionary to map timezone abbreviations to their corresponding UTC offsets.
timezone_map = {
    'CST': '-0600'
}

# Replace the timezone abbreviation in the string with its corresponding UTC offset
for abbreviation, offset in timezone_map.items():
    ts = ts.replace(abbreviation, offset)

# Convert the modified time string to a datetime object
datetime_object = pd.to_datetime(ts)

print(datetime_object)
```

*[DEMO HERE](https://trinket.io/python3/3840da65b2)*